# Backbone Namespaces Open View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I hope someone could give me some usefull hints.

app.js

```
;(function(app){

'use strict';

app.on('start', function(){
     var view = new app.base.base_documents.views.DokumentenView();
     view.render();
});
```

})(window.app);

Is there a shorter and better way to write the follwing code

```
var view = new app.base.base_documents.views.CustomView();
view.render();
```

Maybe there is a way to call my view like this:

```
var view = CustomView();
view.render()
```

My views.js

;(function (app) {

```
'use strict';

app.module('base.base_documents.views', function (module, App, Backbone, Marionette) {


    module.CustomView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    ...
    });
}(app));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where your views are kept (namespace-wise), you could pass `app.base.base_documents.views` to the IIFE:

```
;(function(app, views){

  'use strict';

  app.on('start', function(){
       var view = new views.DokumentenView();
       view.render();
  });
})(window.app, window.app.base.base_documents.views);
```

But you may have views inside other nested namespaces, so for those you need to do the same - which in the end gives a similar result. You either step down through the namespaces when rendering the view, or you do it when passing the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. If I do your workaround i got the following error-message:backbone.marionette.js:2171 Uncaught TypeError: this._initChildViewStorage is not a function(…)  Any Ideas ?constructor @ backbone.marionette.js:2171
constructor @ backbone.marionette.js:2881
child @ backbone.js:1884
(anonymous function) @ VM1691:1
success @ app.js:38
fire @ jquery.js:974
fireWith @ jquery.js:1084
done @ jquery.js:7803
callback @ jquery.js:8518

Comment: No idea what that could be. Sounds specific to your application. Try to verify that the `views` parameter is indeed what you expect, and that the `DokumentenView` is present inside the object (`views`).

Comment: If it helped you, would you mind marking it as the answer? ;)